# Why am I seeing repeated values for both columns on my table even though I'm using a Set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

Hey can anyone tell me why I'm getting repeated values for both `oppDesc` and `contestEntriesAmt` even though I'm using a Set for `oppDesc` (`contestEntriesAmt` doesn't need to be in a Set because nothing's being repeated)?

Why are both `oppDesc` and `contestEntriesAmt` repeating?  It just doesn't make sense.

Whenever I remove `entries.map(() => {...})`, `oppDesc` shows up correctly (no repeated values).

```
const oppDescData = () => {
    const dataOppDesc = oppDesc
    let desc = [];

    dataOppDesc.forEach((oppD) => {desc.push(oppD.oppDescription);});

    const dataNumEntries = numEntries
    let entries          = [];

    dataNumEntries.forEach((entry) => {entries.push(entry.SumOfEntries);});

    let filteredDesc = new Set(desc);
    let oppDescription = [...filteredDesc];

    return (
        <>
            {
                oppDescription.map((oppDesc) => {
                    return entries.map((contestEntriesAmt) => {
                        return(
                            <tr>
                                <td>{oppDesc}</td>
                                <td>{contestEntriesAmt}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                })
            }
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You getting duplicates as you are doing intersection of two lists by calling map in map. Says you have two lists, each 10 items, in result with your code you will get 100 tr entries. Even if you will use sets, and each value will be unique per array - this still will happens

Comment: How would I merge these correctly so I don't get duplicates?  I'm so lost on this :(. I need to populate two columns.

Comment: You need better explain what is logic that you trying to implement. As you said you need to merge, but what type of merge you need? Fully sure that intersection is not what you need, then maybe just concat?

Comment: I'm trying to implement both columns having non repeated values.  They data is correct, but the values are repeating.  How do I get rid of the repeated values?

Comment: So you simply need two columns from these two lists, but in what way they should be joined?

Comment: They need to be separate columns with non repeating values, not sure what's the name for a join like that.

Comment: Ok then you need a simple for, from zero to biggest length of these two arrays, then just print elements by index keeping in mind that you need to check if element by idx exists